# SwiftUI changes in model not updating view

Tags: swift, swiftui, viewmodel, observedobject

I use URLSession to connect to a websocket server. With the callback functions I update the var "isConnectionOpen" inside the Model/Service. Even though I use the @Published modifier the update is not redrawing my view. Below you can find a short overview.

**Model**

```
var isConnectionOpen = false
func openConnection()

    // callback functions
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didOpenWithProtocol protocol: String?) {
        print("WebSocket connection opened")
isConnectionOpen = true
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
@Published var model = Model()
```

**View**

```
@ObservedObject var vm: VM

var body: some View {
    Text(vm.model.isConnectionOpen ? "Connected" : "Not connected")
}
```

Comment: Is you model a `struct` or a `class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example of using @ObservedObject in the parent view you have to declare the object as @StateObject

```
 class Model: ObservableObject{
    @Published var isConnectionOpen = false
    
    func openConnection(){
        // ...
        // if is completed set isConnectionOpen = true
        isConnectionOpen = true

    }
}

struct ChildView: View{
    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("tap-to-connect"){
                model.openConnection()
            }
            Text(model.isConnectionOpen ? "Connected" : "Not connected")

        }
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View{
        ChildView(model: model)
//            .onAppear(perform: {
//                // Mark: Connect to server
//                model.openConnection()
//            })
    }

}
```